# Reduce data returned by ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query.

```
GET sales/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "ean":  ["8719092410766", "8719092444716"]
    }
  }, 
  "_source": ["ean"],
  "size": 10000
}
```

Which gives me the following result.

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sales",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "CuDvcGIBmw7bqEEVBvZq",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ean": "8719092444716"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sales",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "DeDvcGIBmw7bqEEVBvZq",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ean": "8719092410766"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sales",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "9yHvcGIBbx4s3M8zD9_u",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ean": "8719092410766"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is a lot of data, and I am actually only interested in the sources. What I would like it to return is this:

```
["8719092444716", "8719092410766"]
```

Or as closely as possible to it. Is there any trick that I can use to reduce the amount of data fetched from the database? I read about `filter_path`, but ElasticSearch 6.0 doesn't seem to recognize this keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could use `filter_path` ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering)), which is a parameter you can add to your request's URL and specify (comma separated) the data components you want to **include** in the response. For example, if you are interested in only the hits and none of the ES metrics, you could do (curl example)

```
curl http://localhost:9200/index01/type01/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
```

, and get the following response

```
{
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_index" : "index01",
            "_id" : "6PHE_WIBts_g9zk4nzM5",
            "_type" : "type01",
            "_source" : {
               "title" : "Radioactive Honeycomb"
            },
            "_score" : 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Hope that helps (I'm using ES 6.0 btw).

Comment: When I try this (using Kibana dev tools), I get a 400 with this message: `"reason": "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [filter_path]."`

Comment: I figured it out. I assumed that the query parameter would be part of the body, but it can only be given as a query parameter. I don't see why Elastic made this choice, and not have all the options in a single interface.